# Why does this variable declaration statement work?

Tags: javascript

For the variable test below:

```
test = (window.a=window.a ||1);
```

Where `a` may or may not be defined.

If `a` is defined then test is `a` and if it isn't then test is `1`. But I don't understand how `window.a=window.a` checks if a is defined?

Comment: Wrong precedence. It is `window.a || 1` that checks if `a` is defined.

Comment: Please have a look at [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: The expression is interpreted as if it were parenthesized like this: `(window.a = (window.a || 1))`

Answer (score 0):

`window.a=window.a || 1` isn't doing any checking. It's actually doing an assignment.

It's basically setting a default value. It could be expanded like so:

```
window.a = window.a || 1;
test = window.a;
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.a = window.a` does not checks anything. First, `window.a ||`1 checks whether a is defined and returns `window.a` if it is or `1` if it is not. Then, it assigns the result to the `window.a`, so it's `window.a` or `1`. And then, it assignes `window.a` to the `test`.